# Error ClassNotFoundException java

Tags: java

No entiendo el error este, el código me parece que esta bien. Pero nose porque salta esta excepción. Si alguien me puede explicar a que se debe y como arreglarlo se agradece.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JDBCIIpuntoI {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
     try
     {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection
     ("jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.17/ejemplo","root","austria");
     DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conexion.getMetaData();
     ResultSet resul = null;
     String nombre = dbmd.getDatabaseProductName();
     String driver = dbmd.getDriverName();
     String url = dbmd.getURL();
     String usuario = dbmd.getUserName();
     System.out.printf("Nombre: %s %n", nombre);
     System.out.printf("Nombre: %s %n", driver);
     System.out.printf("Nombre: %s %n", url);
     System.out.printf("Nombre: %s %n", usuario);
     resul = dbmd.getTables(null,"ejemplo",null,null);

     while (resul.next()){
         String catalogo = resul.getString(1);
         String esquema = resul.getString(2);
         String tabla = resul.getString(3);
         String tipo = resul.getString(4);
         System.out.printf("%s - Catalogo: %s, Esquema: %s, Nombre: %s %n", tipo,catalogo, esquema, tabla);
     }
     conexion.close();
     }
     catch (ClassNotFoundException cn) {cn.printStackTrace();}
     catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
     }
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Seguro que tienes los archivos o dependencias de JDBC correctamente? ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error completo? Ponlo en la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Voy se me olvido ponerlo ;)

Comment: Desde JDBC 4 (me parece)  ya no es necesario usar `Class.forName`, además, el valor que pones ahí es muy raro, tiene una `cj` que no sé de dónde sale. Prueba así: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`  y hasta puedes probar a omitirlo, si tienes JDBC 4+  no lo necesitas.

Comment: @A.Cedano no podemos saberlo hasta que no indique que versión de driver ODBC y mysql tiene instalados

Comment: @RuslanLópez tengo entendido que no es necesario en ninguno desde JDBC 4+, pero no tengo una fuente que lo diga con toda claridad. Habría que revisar más detenidamente algunas fuentes como: [Fuente 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) /  [Fuente 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html#package.description)  /  [Fuente 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220844/5587982) ... etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano el problema es que no dice que isa JDBC4, este error es común cuando no instalan el driver en windows, por ello se necesita más información

Comment: @A.Cedano Perdon la tardanza. Si hay un cj es porque tengo configurado un drive con hibernate en otro proyecto y en este e aprovechado el driver creado para usarlo.